# Verifying existence Backbone.js model's before rendering view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, google-chrome-extension

My Chrome Extension has two main components scripts:

1. `popup.js` and `popup.html` - the extension logic and UI respectively.
2. `scrape.js` - JavaScript embedded into a webpage to scrape a key value.

`scrape.js` - is very simple. It does only two things:

1. Scrape webpage for key.
2. Run 6 distinct database queries using scraped key.
   Because of the library involved (outside of my control) the database queries must be run from scrape.js (i.e. in the context of tab's web page).

When (or more importantly, **if**) each of 6 queries completes, `scrape.js` calls `popup.js` notifying it some data is ready for rendering.

Upon receiving the callback notification `popup.js` uses Backbone models and views to render the data provided by `scrape.js`:

```
var modelA = Backbone.Model.extend({...});
modelA.set({...});

var modelB = Backbone.Model.extend({...});
modelB.set({...});
```

These models are created from callbacks and only exist if the relevant callback is made by `scrape.js` to `popup.js`. In this sense the models and any views that render them are **optional**.

If a callback is made, a model is stored in a global variable `modeInstances` so I may render it later. If all 6 queries complete, 6 callbacks are made and 6 Backbone model instances will be stored in `modeInstances`.

When `popup.js` receives a **final callback**, it renders any models and views:

```
modelInstances.a = modelA; // Could be undefined.
modelInstances.b = modelB; // Could be undefined.
```

I have three Backbone.js views, one of these views renders both models (A and B):

```
var viewA = new Views.ViewA({
  modelA: modelInstances.modelA,
});
viewA.render();

var viewB = new Views.ViewB({
  modelB: modelInstances.modelB,
});
viewB.render();

var viewAandB = new Views.ViewAandB({
  modelA: modelInstances.modelA,
  modelB: modelInstances.modelB,
});
viewAandB.render();
```

If either modelA or modelB were not created, I receive an exception in the View's initialize method (**read code comments below**):

```
Views.ViewAandB = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function(options) {
    var self = this;

    // Even if models are undefined, this is OK.
    this.modelA = options.modelA;
    this.modelB = options.modelB;

    _.bindAll(this, 'render');

    // This fails if models are undefined.
    this.bidderModel.bind('change', this.render);
    this.buyerModel.bind('change', this.render);
  },
});
```

I could surround the the code which creates the view with a condition, but this feels messy:

```
if (modelInstances.modelA && modelInstances.modelB) {
    var viewAandB = new Views.ViewAandB({
      modelA: modelInstances.modelA,
      modelB: modelInstances.modelB,
    });
    viewAandB.render();
}
```

I could check inside the view's initialize and render methods, but this too feels messy since it must be duplicated in any method using the view's model:

```
initialize: function(options) {
  var self = this;
  var haveModels = (options.modelA && options.modelB);

  if(!haveModels) {
    // No data.
    return;
  }

  // Even if models are undefined, this is OK.
  this.modelA = options.modelA;
  this.modelB = options.modelB;

  _.bindAll(this, 'render');

  // This fails if models are undefined.
  this.bidderModel.bind('change', this.render);
  this.buyerModel.bind('change', this.render);
},
```

Question: How should I check the necessary models are created when rendering 'optional' views?

Comment: this seems to be an xy problem... you say *"this feels messy"* ... callbacks, global variables... those feels messy too. You should explain what you're trying to implement, maybe there's a better way of doing it. From what you're sharing with us, all I can say is use an `if` condition.

Comment: @T J - Thanks. And updated my question.